# Swift if let evaluates successfully on Optional(nil)

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, swift, option-type

I have a custom object called Field. I basically use it to define a single field in a form.

```
class Field {

    var name: String
    var value: Any?

    // initializers here...
}
```

When the user submits the form, I validate each of the `Field` objects to make sure they contain valid values. Some fields aren't required so I sometimes deliberately set `nil` to the `value` property like this:

```
field.value = nil
```

This seems to pose a problem when I use an if-let to determine whether a field is nil or not.

```
if let value = field.value {
    // The field has a value, ignore it...
} else {
    // Add field.name to the missing fields array. Later, show the
    // missing fields in a dialog.
}
```

I set breakpoints in the above if-else and **when `field.value` has been deliberately set to nil, it goes through the if-let block, not the else.** However, for the fields whose `field.value` I left uninitialized and unassigned, **the program goes to the else block.**

I tried printing out `field.value` and `value` inside the if-let block:

```
if let value = field.value {
    NSLog("field.value: \(field.value), value: \(value)")
}
```

And this is what I get:

> field.value: Optional(nil), value: nil

So I thought that maybe with optionals, it's one thing to be uninitialized and another to have the value of nil. But even adding another if inside the if-let won't make the compiler happy:

```
if let value = field.value {
    if value == nil { // Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(Any, NilLiteralConvertible)'
    }
}
```

How do I get around this? I just want to check if the `field.value` is `nil`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Which Xcode version do you use?

Comment: Xcode 6 GM. Tried restarting it, still no luck. :(

Comment: Can you post a complete self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Don't be tempted to use `Any`. By using `Any` you are giving up half of the Swift features (strong types). Why don't you use a nice generic type there?

Comment: @MartinR Hm, you're right. I can't reproduce it in a new project. I'll see where else I could be doing something wrong. Code, for reference: http://pastebin.com/BEJDXvYP

Comment: @Sulthan Because it can be a String for fields that require text input, or a Core Data object for fields that require selection.

Comment: @MattQuiros: So use an enum with two cases: `case CoreDataObject(NSManagedObject)` and `case StringField(String)`, then use an optional of that enum as the type instead of `Any?`.

Comment: I added the proposed enum to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is because `Any?` allows any value and `Optional.None` is being interpreted as just another value, since `Optional` is an enum!

`AnyObject?` should be unable to do this since it only can contain `Optional.Some([any class object])`, which does not allow for the case `Optional.Some(Optional)` with the value `Optional.None`.

This is deeply confusing to even talk about. The point is: try `AnyObject?` instead of `Any?` and see if that works.

---

More to the point, one of Matt's comment mentions that the reason he wants to use `Any` is for a selection that could be either a field for text input or a field intended to select a Core Data object.

The Swifty thing to do in this case is to use an [enum with associated values](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_227), basically the same thing as a [tagged/discriminated union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). Here's how to declare, assign and use such an enum:

```
enum DataSelection {
    case CoreDataObject(NSManagedObject)
    case StringField(String)
}

var selection : DataSelection?

selection = .CoreDataObject(someManagedObject)

if let sel = selection { // if there's a selection at all
    switch sel {
        case .CoreDataObject(let coreDataObj):
            // do what you will with coreDataObj
        case .StringField(let string):
            // do what you will with string
    }
}
```

Using an enum like this, there's no need to worry about which things could be hiding inside that `Any?`. There are two cases and they are documented. And of course, the selection variable can be an optional without any worries.

Comment: The correct answer is "avoid `Any` at all cost". If you are using optional `Any`, you are screwed.

Comment: Yes, because it does not seem that there's a way for the language to distinguish between `Optional.None` being intended for use as the actual value or to mark the absence of a value in optional `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tip to replace my `Any?` type with an enum but I couldn't get this error out of my head. Changing my approach doesn't change the fact that something is wrong with my current one and I had to figure out how I arrived at an `Optional(nil)` output.

I was able to reproduce the error by writing the following view controller in a new single-view project. Notice the `init` signature.

```
import UIKit

class Field {
    var name: String = "Name"
    var value: Any?

    init(_ name: String, _ value: Any) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
    }
}

class AppState {
    var currentValue: Field?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let f = Field("Amount", AppState().currentValue)
        NSLog("\(f.value)")

    }
}
```

In short, I was passing a nil value (`AppState().currentValue`) to an initializer that accepts `Any`, and assigns it to a property whose type is `Any?`. The funny thing here is if I directly passed `nil` instead, the compiler will complain:

```
let f = Field("Amount", nil) // Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'
```

It seems that somewhere along the way, Swift wraps the `nil` value of `AppState().currentValue` in an optional, hence `Optional(nil)`.

Comment: `nil` doesn't exist as a value (only as a keyword), but `Optional.None` is the default value of any optional variable and it prints `nil` when asked to describe itself.