# How to get a swift enum's associated value regardless of the enum case

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, swift

I have an object FormField which has two properties: a String `name`, and a `value` which can accept any type--hence I've made it `Any!`. However, I've been told in [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863694/swift-if-let-evaluates-successfully-on-optionalnil) to use an enum with associated values instead of `Any!`.

```
enum Value {
    case Text(String!)
    case CoreDataObject(NSManagedObject!)
}

class FormField {
    var name: String
    var value: Value?
    // initializers...
}
```

This approach makes it awfully verbose to check for nullity however. If I wanted to display an alert view for all the missing fields in the form, I'll have to repeat a nil check for every case in a switch statement:

```
for field in self.fields {
    if let value = field.value {
        switch value {
        case .Text(let text):
            if text == nil {
                missingFields.append(field.name)
            }
        case .CoreDataObject(let object):
            if object == nil {
                missingFields.append(field.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a shorter way of accessing the enum's associated value, regardless of the type? If I make FormField.value an `Any!` the above code would be as easy as:

```
for field in self.fields {
    if field.value == nil {
        missingFields.append(field.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove a few lines by using a `where` clause in your `case` statements: `case .Text(let text) where text == nil:`.

Comment: @MikeS Great tip, thanks. That way I can have a `where` clause for every case that can be nil and let it fallthrough. I'm going back with `Any!` though. Making it an enum requires me to write code that's too verbose.

Comment: Isn't that just moving the verbosity around though? I'd presume that at some point you'll have to know the actual type of those `Any`s, and then you'll be doing a bunch of `if value is String`, `if value is NSManagedObject`, etc.

Comment: Also, `value` is already an optional in your `FormField` class. If you're only setting the `FormField`'s `value` when there is one, you can already just just check `if field.value == nil`. That means you also don't need to make your `enum`'s associated values implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Comment: @MikeS Unless I make the associated values an optional, I can't compare them to nil. The compiler complains about how the associated value's type doesn't conform to `NilLiteralConvertible`.

Comment: @MikeS And true, `Any!` just moves the verbosity around but with way less lines of code. I don't have to check `if value is String` or `if value is NSManagedObject` but I just downcast them when assigning to the corresponding parameter; eg `expense.description = fields[0].value as String` then `expense.category = fields[1].value as SPRCategory` etc.

Comment: What does it mean to be `.Text(nil)` in your data model? Why not just be `.Nothing`? Since `FormField.value()` is already optional, why do you need another layer of "emptiness" at all? If they really can be empty, it is much better to use an explicit optional (`?`) rather than an implicit one (`!`). A lot of what you're doing here is fighting the type-safety, which is going to cause you to have to check things constantly. Often a simpler data model will give you the conciseness you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define a method `isMissing()` inside the `enum` - write it once and only once.  Then you get nearly exactly what you prefer:

```
for field in self.fields {
    if field.value.isMissing() {
        missingFields.append(field.name)
    }
}
```

It would look something like this (from the Swift Interpreter):

```
  1> class Foo {}
   >
  2> enum Value { 
  3.     case One(Foo!) 
  4.     case Two(Foo!) 
  5.      
  6.     func isMissing () -> Bool { 
  7.         switch self { 
  8.         case let .One(foo): return foo == nil 
  9.         case let .Two(foo): return foo == nil 
 10.         } 
 11.     } 
 12. }    
 13> let aVal = Value.One(nil)
aVal: Value = One {
  One = nil
}
 14> aVal.isMissing()
$R0: Bool = true
```

Comment: Great idea! Might be I'll use this in some other situation. Right now, for cases where the associated value isn't nil, I can't pinpoint which `FormField` object it is an associated value for if I have a form that has multiple `UITextField`s (i.e., all of them will hold values of type `.Text(String!)` and accessing the `String!` alone doesn't tell me which field it's for).

Comment: @Cristik Hm... I think at that time I wanted to have some reflection API (e.g. as seen here https://medium.com/@swiftthesorrow/reflection-in-swift-958824116b07)

Answer (score 7):

With Swift 2 it's possible to get the associated value using reflection.

To make that easier just add the code below to your project and extend your enum with the EVAssociated protocol.

```
    public protocol EVAssociated {
    }

    public extension EVAssociated {
        public var associated: (label:String, value: Any?) {
            get {
                let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
                if let associated = mirror.children.first {
                    return (associated.label!, associated.value)
                }
                print("WARNING: Enum option of \(self) does not have an associated value")
                return ("\(self)", nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can access the .asociated value with code like this:

```
    class EVReflectionTests: XCTestCase {
            func testEnumAssociatedValues() {
                let parameters:[EVAssociated] = [usersParameters.number(19),
usersParameters.authors_only(false)]
            let y = WordPressRequestConvertible.MeLikes("XX", Dictionary(associated: parameters))
            // Now just extract the label and associated values from this enum
            let label = y.associated.label
            let (token, param) = y.associated.value as! (String, [String:Any]?)

            XCTAssertEqual("MeLikes", label, "The label of the enum should be MeLikes")
            XCTAssertEqual("XX", token, "The token associated value of the enum should be XX")
            XCTAssertEqual(19, param?["number"] as? Int, "The number param associated value of the enum should be 19")
            XCTAssertEqual(false, param?["authors_only"] as? Bool, "The authors_only param associated value of the enum should be false")

            print("\(label) = {token = \(token), params = \(param)")
        }
    }

    // See http://github.com/evermeer/EVWordPressAPI for a full functional usage of associated values
    enum WordPressRequestConvertible: EVAssociated {
        case Users(String, Dictionary<String, Any>?)
        case Suggest(String, Dictionary<String, Any>?)
        case Me(String, Dictionary<String, Any>?)
        case MeLikes(String, Dictionary<String, Any>?)
        case Shortcodes(String, Dictionary<String, Any>?)
    }

    public enum usersParameters: EVAssociated {
        case context(String)
        case http_envelope(Bool)
        case pretty(Bool)
        case meta(String)
        case fields(String)
        case callback(String)
        case number(Int)
        case offset(Int)
        case order(String)
        case order_by(String)
        case authors_only(Bool)
        case type(String)
    }
```

The code above is now available as a cocoapod susbspec at
https://github.com/evermeer/Stuff#enum
It also has an other nice enum extension for enumerating all enum values.

Answer (score 0):

If the associated values were of the same type for all enum cases the following approach could help.

```
enum Value {
    case text(NSString!), two(NSString!), three(NSString!) // This could be any other type including AnyClass
}

// Emulating "fields" datastruct for demo purposes (as if we had struct with properties).
typealias Field = (en: Value, fieldName: String)
let fields: [Field] = [(.text(nil),"f1"), (.two(nil), "f2"), (.three("Hey"), "f3")] // this is analog of "fields"

let arrayOfFieldNamesWithEmptyEnums: [String] = fields.compactMap({
    switch $0.en {
    case let .text(foo), let .two(foo), let .three(foo): if foo == nil { return $0.fieldName } else { return nil }}
})
print("arrayOfFieldNamesWithEmptyEnums \(arrayOfFieldNamesWithEmptyEnums)")
```

Many other things can be obtained similarly.

```
let arrayOfEnumsWithoutValues: [Value] = fields.compactMap({
    switch $0.en {
    case let .text(foo), let .two(foo), let .three(foo): if foo == nil { return $0.en } else { return nil }}
})
print("arrayOfEnumsWithoutValues \(arrayOfEnumsWithoutValues)")

// just to check ourselves
if let index = arrayOfEnumsWithoutValues.index(where: { if case .two = $0 { return true }; return false }) {
    print(".two found at index \(index)")
}
```