# Generic XCTAssertEqual with AnyObject arguments?

Tags: swift, generics, nslayoutconstraint, xctest, anyobject

When testing `NSLayoutConstraint` items, this line doesn't compile:

```
XCTAssertEqual(firstItem, view1)
```

> Error: Cannot invoke 'XCTAssertEqual' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject, AnyObject)'

To get it to compile without errors or warnings, I have to do:

```
XCTAssertEqual(firstItem as? UIView, view1 as? UIView)
```

But, I don't know if either `firstItem` or `view1` will be a `UIView` or a `UILayoutSupport`, etc.

So, is there a generic way to test this?

For context, I'm doing this inside of a test helper method I wrote:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    func assert(item view1: AnyObject, toItem view2: AnyObject? = nil, attribute attr1: NSLayoutAttribute, relatedBy relation: NSLayoutRelation = .Equal, attribute attr2: NSLayoutAttribute? = nil, multiplier: CGFloat = 1, constant c: CGFloat = 0) {
        let attribute2: NSLayoutAttribute = view2 == nil ? .NotAnAttribute : (attr2 ?? attr1)
        XCTAssertEqual(firstItem as? UIView, view1 as? UIView)
        XCTAssertEqual(firstAttribute, attr1)
        XCTAssertEqual(self.relation, relation)
        XCTAssertEqual(secondItem as? UIView, view2 as? UIView)
        XCTAssertEqual(secondAttribute, attribute2)
        XCTAssertEqual(self.multiplier, multiplier)
        XCTAssertEqual(constant, c)
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you just made a function that returns `true` on an `AnyObject` comparison and use `XCTAssertTrue` instead?

Comment: Thank you. I googled **swift compare anyobject** and found the answer.

Comment: SwiftHamcrest offers another option: `assertThat(firstItem, sameInstance(view1))`

Answer (score -1):

Try `XCTAssertTrue(firstItem === view1)`.

[Swift's identity operator === lets you compare `AnyObject`s in Swift without casting them to a specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32510419/242933).