# Type check operator (is) for check vs homogenous protocol: why can this be done for optionals?

Tags: swift

#### TL;DR

- Why are we allowed to use the type check operator `is` against a homogenous protocol (which may not, in itself, be used as a type) for instances that are optional, when this is (as expected) seemingly not allowed for instances of non-optional types?

#### Background

We can make use of the type check operator (`is`) to check whether an instance is of a certain type, e.g.

```
let a = 1
a is Int    // true
a is String // false
```

On a separate note, homogenous protocols (protocols with `Self` or associated type requirements) cannot be used as concrete types, e.g.

```
protocol Homogenous {
    func foo(_: Self)
}

let b: Homogenous? = nil
    /* error: protocol 'Homogenous' can only be used as a generic constraint 
              because it has Self or associated type requirements            */
```

Hence, it is natural that we shouldn't be able to use the type check operator `is` to check whether an instance is of a homogenous protocol "type". In line with this hypothesis, the following example fails as expected

```
protocol Homogenous {
    func foo(_: Self)
}

extension Homogenous {
    func foo(_: Self) {}
}

extension Int: Homogenous {}

let a: Int = 1

a is Homogenous
    /* error: protocol 'Homogenous' can only be used as a generic constraint 
              because it has Self or associated type requirements            */
```

#### Question

In the discussion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38153698/4573247), it was noted that— peculiarly—we're allowed to use the type check operator `is` for type checking against a homogenous protocol if the instance we're checking is an optional.

```
protocol Homogenous {
    func foo(_: Self)
}

extension Homogenous {
    func foo(_: Self) {}
}

class Foo: Homogenous {}
extension Int: Homogenous {}

let a: Int = 1
let b: String = "one"
let c: Foo = Foo()

/* Generally, we can't type check using 'is' against a homogenous protocol,
   but if the variable we are type checking is an optional, we can.
   Why is this?                                                             */
let bar: Int? = a
bar is Homogenous         // true
Optional(a) is Homogenous // true

let baz: String? = b
baz is Homogenous         // false

let bax: Foo? = c
bax is Homogenous         // true
```

**Question:**

- Why are we allowed to use `is` against a homogenous protocol for instances that are optional?

I might add that we can't emulate this behaviour with a simple enum wrapper

```
enum Wrapper<T> {
    case Some(T)
    case None
}

let a: Int = 1
let foo = Wrapper.Some(a)
foo is Homogenous
    /* error: protocol 'Homogenous' can only ... */
```

Comment: This is probably a bug. I would guess it is connected with the automated promotion of non-optionals to optionals.

Comment: @Sulthan it does indeed seem like a bug, as I can only see this ever used in runtime hacks. I'll wait a few days before filing this, however, in case we're missing some hidden intent.

Comment: The funny thing is that `a is Homogenous` triggers a compilation error but it also triggers  a warning *"test is always true"*. That strikes me as a clear bug. Unfortunately the `is` and `as?` operators behave very strangely right now. I have two bugs reported for them when used with generics.

Comment: @Sulthan yeah I've seen some weirdness with the `is`/`as` keywords w.r.t. prompting warnings (e.g. _"always true"_) while simultaneously triggering errors, so a bit buggy there I guess. Thanks for your feedback, I'll file a bug for this tonight.