# How to represent a generic JSON structure in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, types, codable

I would like to represent a generic JSON object in Swift:

```
let foo: [String: Any] = [
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": "baz",
]
```

But the `[String: Any]` type suggested by the compiler doesn’t really work well. I can’t check two instances of the type for equality, for example, while that should be possible with two JSON trees.

What also doesn’t work is using the `Codable` machinery to encode that value into a JSON string:

```
let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(foo)
```

Which blows up with an error:

```
fatal error: Dictionary<String, Any> does not conform to Encodable because Any does not conform to Encodable.
```

I know I can introduce a precise type, but I am after a generic JSON structure. I even tried to introduce a specific type for generic JSON:

```
enum JSON {
    case string(String)
    case number(Float)
    case object([String:JSON])
    case array([JSON])
    case bool(Bool)
    case null
}
```

But when implementing `Codable` for this enum I don’t know how to implement `encode(to:)`, since a keyed container (for encoding objects) requires a particular `CodingKey` argument and I don’t know how to get that.

Is it really not possible to create an `Equatable` generic JSON tree and encode it using `Codable`?

Comment: Go on SwiftyJSON: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: I already use a different JSON decoding library and if there is no simpler solution, I guess I’d compare the values using `NSDictionary(dictionary: foo).isEqual(to: bar)` rather than switch to a different library. But I’ll take a look, thank you.

Comment: As noted elsewhere, SwiftyJSON is a decent option for now. But depending on where you are in the development lifecycle of your product, you might want to keep an eye on the [built-in JSON encoding coming in Swift 4](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0167-swift-encoders.md).

Comment: A JSON object as parsed from JSON can be a dictionary or an array (both are possible as top level objects), or, if fragments are allowed, a boolean, number or a string. That's why `Any` is used in the parser. Defining equality on dictionaries is very tricky because you need equality to be defined on values which is hard to define for `Any`. In a type-safe language defining JSON as a dictionary is not very flexible. That's why a specific JSON type is better. On a specific JSON type defining equality is trivial. I recommend using SwiftyJSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We will use generic strings as coding keys:

```
extension String: CodingKey {
    public init?(stringValue: String) {
        self = stringValue
    }

    public var stringValue: String {
        return self
    }

    public init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
    }

    public var intValue: Int? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The rest really is just a matter of getting the correct type of container and writing your values to it.

```
extension JSON: Encodable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        switch self {
        case .string(let string):
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encode(string)
        case .number(let number):
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encode(number)
        case .object(let object):
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: String.self)

            for (key, value) in object {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            }
        case .array(let array):
            var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()

            for value in array {
                try container.encode(value)
            }
        case .bool(let bool):
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encode(bool)
        case .null:
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encodeNil()
        }
    }
}
```

Given this, I'm sure you can implement `Decodable` and `Equatable` yourself.

---

Note that this will crash if you try to encode anything other than an array or an object as a top-level element.

Comment: Works wonders, thank you very much! (I have introduced a separate `GenericKey` struct to hold the key, so that I didn’t need to squat on `String`.) I didn’t find a way to represent the “only arrays and objects allowed as top-level objects” constraint in the type, but other than that it’s very nice. I’ll package the code as a library on GitHub, in case anyone is interested. Thanks again!

Comment: There's no need to make a custom `CodingKey` type (or conform `String` to it); just call the given `encode` overloads on a `singleValueContainer`, e.g https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/e5bd36a1d5868b896f09dedad51b9ee9

Answer (score 2):

You could use generics for this:

```
typealias JSON<T: Any> = [String: T] where T: Equatable
```

Comment: No idea why you’re being downvoted without a comment. But this doesn’t work: `'where' clause cannot be attached to a non-generic declaration`. Can I say `Any: Equatable` somehow? I see, it probably [doesn’t make sense in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901105/compare-anyobjects-in-swift-without-casting-them-to-a-specific-type)…

Comment: Not sure why I'm being down voted either. Generic is the way this should be done. This code works perfectly fine for me and compiles no problem. I should add, its Swift 3 code. I'm on Xcode 8.3.2 :)

Comment: That’s something different, though, isn’t it? It’s a generic type that has to be specialized before it can be used for a variable. It looks that what I want is not possible in Swift – [see here for example](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11165).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue but I had too many types that I want to desserialize so I think I would have to enumerate all of them in the JSON enum from the accepted answer. So I created a simple wraper which worked surprisingly well:

```
struct Wrapper: Encodable {
    let value: Encodable
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try value.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}
```

then you could write

```
let foo: [String: Wrapper] = [
    "foo": Wrapper(value: 1),
    "bar": Wrapper(value: "baz"),
]

let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(foo) // now this works
```

Not the prettiest code ever, but worked for any type you want to encode without any additional code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this [BeyovaJSON](https://github.com/Beyova/BeyovaJSON)

```swift
import BeyovaJSON

let foo: JToken = [
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": "baz",
]

let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(foo)
```

Answer (score -1):

From my point of view the most suitable is [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). It has nice API for the developers to be sure how parse and work with `JSON` objects.

`JSON` object have quite nice interface for working with different types of the response.

From the Apple docs:

> Types that conform to the Equatable protocol can be compared for
>   equality using the equal-to operator (==) or inequality using the
>   not-equal-to operator (!=). Most basic types in the Swift standard
>   library conform to Equatable.

Let consider case that you ask.We should just check if `JSON` conforms to protocol `Equatable`.